# Webpack 5: Prevent duplication: Entry dependencies & SplitChunksPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

With Webpack, there is the possibility to avoid **duplicated code**. This feature exists since a long time with `SplitChunksPlugin` or even before `CommonsChunkPlugin` (deprecated).

Looking at the Webpack 5 documentation in the [prevent duplication section](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication), a new option called [`dependOn`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#entry-dependencies) has been added. This option allows to share the modules between the chunks.

However, there is still the option `splitChunksPlugin` and I would like to know what is the difference between both?